# Что означает в запросах wordpress 'posts_per_page' => -1?

Tags: wordpress

Что означает в запросах wordpress: 'posts_per_page' => -1 ??

Answer (score 1):

`'posts_per_page' => -1` - количество выводимых записей на странице

Значение `-1` обозначает, вывести все имеющиеся записи © KAGG Design

Comment: я про '-1' в этом запросе

Comment: Указал про `-1` в ответе

Comment: Уточню формулировку: не "количество может быть любым", а "вывести все имеющиеся записи".

Comment: Благодарю, исправил